# postgresql how to choose specific column from exact same columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table A and B.
If I inner join them like

```
SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN B on A.a = B.a
```

The new table has two exactly the same columns "a".
How do I choose the first column of "a"?
Or how do I avoid generate two same columns after inner join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an alias for each column such as:

```
select
  a.id,
  a.firstname as a_firstname,
  b.firstname as b_firstname
from a inner join b on a.id = b.id
```

That way, for matching ID=1, if firstname is 'John' in table a but 'Jon' in table b, you can print them appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter, they are the same.

But if you don't want duplicates, then `using` does that for you:

```
SELECT *
FROM A INNER JOIN
     B
     USING (a)
```